# Skype for Mac doesn't remember my password

Tags: skype

Since my password is stored in a password manager, this also involved opening up the password manager vault to get to just the Skype password and sign in.

How do I get Skype for Mac to remember my password?

Answer (score 10):

#### By clicking `Sign me in when Skype starts`

If you are on the latest version of Skype, it supports sign-in using Skype Name or Microsoft account.

[image]

If you select, `Sign me in when Skype starts` it automatically stores the password and logs you in the next time. This worked fine for me on the latest version just now.

[image]

On version 7.17 (377), you get the option to select this option from `Preferences`

[image]

Comment: I don't see this option on my screen...

Answer (score 1):

sdayals answer does not seem to apply anymore for the latest version of skype as of today. Here is the solution:

When logged into skype, go to Skype -> Preferences -> General and tick "Sign me in when skype starts"

Comment: The latest Skype for Mac (v. 8.11) has a different Preferences structure, and omits this option.